# Does there exist an operation which partitions any fraction into the sum of the minimum number of unit fractions?

Tags: number-theory, summation, fractions

**Motivation** : I've been interested in finding an operation which partitions a fraction into unit fractions. The following is one of the operations which I've found.

Let's start a rational number $q_0$ which satisfies $0\lt q_0\lt 1$.

**Step 1** : Let $i=0$.

**Step 2** : Finding an integer $k_i$ which satisfies $\frac{1}{k_i}\le q_i\lt \frac{1}{k_i-1}$, let $q_{i+1}=q_i-\frac{1}{k_i}.$

**Step 3** : If $q_{i+1}\not=0$, then go back to step 2 with changing $i$ to $i+1$. If $q_{i+1}=0$, then $\frac{1}{k_0}+\frac1{k_1}+\cdots+\frac1{k_i}$ is what you want.

Though we can show that **this operation does end**, I'll skip the details.

By the way, my operation does not give the sum of the minimum number of unit fractions.

For example, in my operation, we get
$$\frac{19}{88}=\frac15+\frac1{63}+\frac1{27720}.$$
On the other hand, the sum of the minimum number of unit fractions is 
$$\frac{19}{88}=\frac18+\frac1{11}.$$

I've been finding an operation which partitions any fraction into the sum of the minimum number of unit fractions, but I'm facing difficulty.

Here is my question.

**Question** : Does there exist an operation which partitions any fraction into the sum of the minimum number of unit fractions?

If you have any helpful information, please let me know it. I need your help.

Comment: When I compute $\frac18+\frac1{11}$ I get $\frac{19}{88}$, not $\frac{11}{88}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Thank you for pointing it out. Just a big mistake.

Comment: Your greedy algorithm was used by Fibonacci I believe to decompose any fraction to unit fractions.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EgyptianFraction.html refers to Hoffman's book and claims there is no known algorithm yet to find the decomposition into smallest number of unit fractions.

Comment: Special cases are known, so for e.g. $p, q$ odd primes, we have $\dfrac{2}{p} = \dfrac{1}{(p+1)/2} + \dfrac{1}{p(p+1)/2}$ and $\dfrac{2}{pq} = \dfrac{2}{p+q}(\dfrac{1}{p} + \dfrac{1}{q})$ etc.

Comment: @Macavity : Thank you for nice info.

Comment: @Macavity : By the way, why you used the word 'greedy'? It made me laugh.

Comment: Oh - it is just that each time you are trying to get the largest unit fraction out of the remainder, in a sense trying to reduce the problem as much as possible at each step without thought of future implications.  Hence "greedy" is often used to describe such algorithms.  Thought rarely optimal, in several cases such algorithms work fine.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that.